# check if the image is in assets folder if image exists return its path in android

Tags: android, image, path, assets

I have some images in assets folder. 
Now i want a code to check if the image exists. And if image exits then it has to return its path. 
So what can be the possible steps to find a path of images or text files in assets folder in android?

I used this method: but i want to get the path of images stored in assets folder.

```
public String filePath(String image) throws IOException{
         String myfilepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/"+image;
            return myfilepath;

        }
```

Comment: WOW!!! Directly asking about code **Now i want a code to check if the image exists..**.

Comment: the meaning was to ask the method to find the path of the image !

Comment: You can get image or file from Assert only if you know name of file or image.

Comment: check my edited question! and give me suggestion about how to get the path of the images stored in assets folder! thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public String filePath(String image,Context _context)
{
   File file = new File(_context.getCacheDir()+File.separator+image);

   if (file.exists()) 
      return file.getPath();
   else
      return null;       

}
```

Answer (score 0):

first you must get list with all files in assets

private String [ ] listAssetFiles(String path) {

String [ ] list;
    try {
        list = getAssets().list(path);
        if (list.length > 0) {
            // T

```
his is a folder
            for (String file : list) {
                if (!listAssetFiles(path + "/" + file))
}
        } 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
return list; 
}
```

and call listAssetFiles("")